# The conditional probability given a joint pdf

Tags: statistics, continuity, conditional-probability

Let X and Y have the joint pdf $f(x,y) = 8x(1-y)$, $0 < y < 1$, and $0 < x < 1-y$

Compute $P(Y < X |X\leq1/4)$

I worked out that the marginal pdf of $x$ is $4x$ and that the conditional pdf is $2(1-y)$ I'm just not sure where to go from there.

Answer = 29/93

Comment: Sorry it wasn't showing for some reason

Comment: What are the ranges of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Without mentioning the support of distributions, pdfs are meaningless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(Y<X|X\leq \frac{1}{4})=\frac{P(Y<X\leq \frac{1}{4})}{P(X \leq \frac{1}{4})}$. Calculate $P(Y<X\leq \frac{1}{4})=\int_0^{1/4}\int_0^{x}8x(1-y)dydx=\frac{29}{768}$ and compute $P(X\leq \frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{8}$. The final answer comes to be $\frac{29}{96}$. Please recheck the numerical computations.